# Playing a game "Made with Unity", i'm getting - install Visual C++ Redistributable 2015

Tags: games, c++

My laptop is running Ubuntu 20.04. When i launch the game it says it was "Made with Unity"  (nothing to do with Unity desktop), and powered by VNgine
When i select,"New Game", I get a white screen, and the following message, "if you see a white screen, please install Visual C++ Redistributable 2015".  I don't know what to do.

Comment: How do you launch the game?

Comment: Unity is a cross-platform game engine, but it sounds like this game was compiled for Windows. If you're launching it through Wine try looking up winetricks. If you're launching it through Steam look up "Proton with winetricks" or "SteamPlay with winetricks" (without quotes on both) AND if you can manage submit a bug report to the developers on Steam as that should be installed automatically.